# C++ rand() always giving same TWO values... and then working perfectly

Tags: c++, random

First, I know the basic principle of planting a time seed, and my program's outputs are *partially* random. But this baffles me.

On subsequent executions of the program, the seven randomly generated values may look like this:

`14 14 47 70 84 2 24`

`14 28 42 52 31 10 12`

`63 25 4 50 20 27 56`

`63 19 55 44 65 60 52`

`14 16 17 40 54 77 4`

`63 6 79 36 51 85 39`

**The rest of the values appear random, but the first value is always either 14 or 63. Why is this happening, and how can I make it completely random?**

The code is supposed to draw a random Scrabble letter without replacement, with a cout statement added for debugging purposes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string bag = "AAAAAAAAABBCCDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEFFGGGHHIIIIIIIIIJKLLLLMMNNNNNNOOOOOOOOPPQRRRRRRSSSSTTTTTTUUUUVVWWXYYZ";

    srand(time(0));
    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++)
    {
        int i = rand()%bag.size();
        cout << i << ' ';
        bag.erase(i,1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- Compiled in MacOS Catalina 10.15 terminal
- Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
- Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
- Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
- Thread model: posix

Comment: Please make a [mre]. It seems you could move the code in `Player::letter` to `main` and still reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @cigien Done. ‎

Comment: May I offer an alternative implementation that doesn't require repeated `erase` calls? You could [std::random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the bag and then just look at the `a`th element of the shuffled bag.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's much better now. Note that the context is still not very helpful, because it's not reproducible. Also, have you tested the code in your latest edit to see if it produces the same results, i.e. the first number is not very random?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. I'm getting random looking numbers. Can you add details about which compiler you're using, as well as the compilation commands?

Comment: Yes, I'm still seeing the behavior in the second example. I honestly don't know a thing about compilers, but it's the Mac terminal running on Catalina. Command is just g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -Wall and ./test.exe.

Comment: @cigien could still be UB then ;) but it probably isn't...

Comment: Add that information to the question, along with the result of `g++ --version`.

Comment: how quickly are you successively executing the program?  If you do it very fast, you might have the first number be the same, as srand(time(0)) is not seeding a different value yet. if you wait 1 or 2 seconds after each execution I have nice  looking random numbers each time

Comment: @geebert I'm not doing it particularly fast, waiting longer has no effect, and separate attempts minutes apart all have the same result.

Comment: `rand` is far from the best random number generator. It can be pretty damn bad, actually. [Here is a presentation on how bad and some better alternatives.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Please modify the line `srand(time(0));` to `srand(time(0)); cout << time(0) << " ";` and try to run the program several times. Post new outputs.

Comment: Why you're not using [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) is the real question here. It is the cat's whiskers, and I *strongly* encourage what it offers.

Comment: @S.M. New outputs: 1607326196 63 77 56 91 1 78 52; 1607326199 14 3 69 81 8 36 0; 1607326201 14 94 24 75 53 69 88; 1607326203 14 88 44 69 4 10 84; 1607326204 63 85 6 67 87 27 36

Comment: Looks good. It seems the C runtime library in your Mac is broken.

Comment: My curiosity is getting to me. When you [run this](https://godbolt.org/z/brKx4q) ? I concur with Nathan's approach, btw. Just put together your letter "bag", shuffle it, and iterate over it to get your random sequence without replacement.

Comment: @WhozCraig Compile error. Does it compile for you?

Comment: You might consider simply throwing away the first few values returned from `rand()`. After seeding with `srand()` use a loop to call `rand()` a few times, hopefully mixing its internal state so you don't have this problem. Ideally you should switch to using the much better functions in the C++ `<random>` header.

Comment: Alternative to your algorithm is to `std::shuffle` your letters, and then picks the first ones.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you It not only compiles for me, it compiles on the site I linked it to you with. Pretty good chance you're either not using a C++11 compatible toolchain, or you are, but don't have the proper language level set (-std=c++11 for g++ and clang++).

Comment: I think this is just macOS having a particularly bad rand(). There are a few examples online of people with similar complaints. I'd switch up your seed or use a better generator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742394/4386278 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879475/4386278 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879475/4386278

Comment: Was this wrapped in a script that ran the program a lot of times in a loop (or in succession)?

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained in comments, it looks like your compiler's C runtime library has a bad rand function.

But you're not using C, you're using C++! Starting at C++11, you have all sorts of random-number generation facilities available in the C++ standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device eng; // or any other type of engine
    using dist_params = typename std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type;
    int max = 99;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist (0, max);
    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++)
    {
        int i = dist(eng);
        std::cout << i << ' ';
        dist.param(dist_params{0, max});
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Or, what I expect you were really going for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    std::string bag0 = "AAAAAAAAABBCCDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEFFGGGHHIIIIIIIIIJKLLLLMMNNNNNNOOOOOOOOPPQRRRRRRSSSSTTTTTTUUUUVVWWXYYZ";

    std::random_device eng;
    time_t t;
    using dist_params = typename std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>::param_type;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist;
    for (auto j = 0; j<100; ++j)
    {
        auto bag = bag0;
        for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++)
        {
            dist.param(dist_params{0, (bag.length())-1});
            int i = dist(eng);
            std::cout << bag[i] << ' ';
            bag.erase(i, 1);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only caveat is that `random_device` may not produce random numbers on your platform.

Answer (score -3):

`rand()` or `std::rand()` never generates **true** random number. It generates **pseudo-random** numbers. This is because computers are unable to generate truly random numbers itself, it requires assistance. Let's say you pressed a key exactly 2.054 seconds after the previous keypress. This is truly a random number. Computers use this data to generate truly random numbers. `rand()` or `std::rand()` generates a pseudo-random number, so needs to be seeded (with `srand()` or `std::srand()`). If the number you used to seed isn't random, the output wouldn't be random too. Moreover, you are using `time()` (or `std::time()`) which returns an `int` holding the number of seconds passed since epoch. So if you execute the program multiple times too rapidly, the seed would be the same and the output too. It also seems that your standard library a bad `rand()` or `std::rand()` function.

#### Example:

Output of the program (compiled from your code) executed 10 times rapidly (environment: Ubuntu, bash):

```
$ for i in {0..9} ; do ./a.out ; done
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42 
50 11 3 60 36 17 42
```

#### What to do?

I can suggest you use another time function to seed, which outputs time in milliseconds (or even nanoseconds) or get your own random number generator. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to know how pseudo-random number generators work. This will also help you to build your own as it seems that your standard library gives a bad `rand()` or `std::rand()` function.

Comment: But the OP's output sequences are clearly different, except for the first number.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Maybe OP is executing the program coincidentally (or programmatically) in such times, when outputs are like that.

Comment: Do you know the odds of that happening every time?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't know, but it is possible to do that with the correct algorithm. Maybe the C or C++ of OP's system has bugs.

Comment: That is not what is happening. It'll be a poor rand() combined with the poor seed (the high bits take years to change)

Comment: I remember hearing about, but don't recall encountering, `rand` implementations where the first value had to be discarded.